# My HUD disappeared

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Minecraft Bedrock Edition on Xbox One, on a server, and my HUD suddenly disappeared - my hotbar, my hunger, my health bar, and my crosshair were suddenly invisible. I saved and quit and logged back in, but it was still different. I also turned off "Hide HUD", and I could still see my hand, and I could access my inventory, mine and place items, but I still can't see my HUD.
What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: And re-enabling the 'hide HUD' option doesn't work? Or did you change the HUD opacity, perhaps? Also try resetting your graphic options to their default settings (if in-game settings won't work, try your general Xbox settings).

Comment: I enabled and de-enabled the hide HUD but that didn't work. I didn't change the HUD opacity but after it happened I played around with the slider. I was watching it as the HUD suddenly dissapeared, I was doing something in my crafting bench, and maybe coincedentally, I pressed like a and b and it suddenly went away. I don't know if it was the buttons that did it because I tried different combinations with my buttons and none of them worked.

Comment: I also put my video (graphic settings) back to default and it still was no-good.

Comment: And how have you fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug too while I was playing on a server.

I got my HUD back by restarting my game. If you need help with restarting Minecraft then I can tell you how later on.

Comment: I restarted (I think) because I went into the xbox main menu and quit minecraft then loaded it back up again, went into the server and it still had no visible HUd. I could still see my hand though and played some normal bedwars.