# Hotbar won’t show? Unable to scroll?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft PE hotbar, health bar, and hunger bar won’t show. The weird thing is, my hand is still there. I’m also unable to scroll through servers, games, etc. I need help. Now.

Comment: See also [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/367317/my-hud-disappeared?rq=1). The OP mentioned they had fixed the issue, but not answered their own question yet. These can be merged when a working answer appears.

Answer (score 2):

Go to options -> the bottom tab on the left -> the very bottom. You'll see a button called "Hide GUI," and if it's selected, unselect it. That button hides you're hotbar and hunger bar.